# Change image based on timer

Tags: cocoa-touch, nstimer

I want to be able to change the image that is shown in my image view based on a timer, so that the image changes every .5 seconds. How would I go about doing something like this? I know how to change the images, I just don't know how to work off the timer.

Comment: There's plenty of Apple documentation, and lots of questions on SO, about how to use a timer. Please search and try something before posting a new question.

Answer (score 3):

Try one of these:

One: Reading [NSTimer's documentation on Apple Developer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html).

Two: Do something like this:

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.5f target:self selector:@selector(updateImage) repeats:YES userInfo:nil];

- (void)updateImage
{
    if (++counter >= imagesArray.count) counter = 0;
    imageView.image = [imagesArray objectAtIndex:counter]; // or whatever else
}
```

Comment: Just for the reference, you may want to add a 'reset condition' for that counter, because otherwise you'll run out of array elements before long. Other than that, this seems like the perfectly correct solution.

Comment: As I said, just for the sake of completeness ;) After all, we don't want the OP to run into the next problem, because he followed the supplied code to a T, right? :D

Comment: @ATaylor yes of course sir. And that's also the reason for me writing "or whatever" in a comment.

Comment: @H2CO3 how would I create an array of images? I have tried a few things but none of them work. Also im assuming "counter" is the timer?

Comment: @user1438042 alloc-init some UIImages then add them to an NSMutableArray. And no, counter is not the timer (did you see me assigning the return value of the NSTimer method call to it?)

Comment: @user1438042 this code is **example**. I don't know what code you have exactly, so the code I provided is not to be copied verbatim in your sources. Please make some effort to understand what it does and what the essential parts are, and read the corresponding manuals. Thanks. (Sorry, I really can't explain it further.)

Comment: @user1438042 It's an integer. Logically, you could use a mechanism like the one I described to obtain a "next image". Basically: nevermind, I gave you the timer method, now adapt it to your particular implementation.